# sketch third derivative of cubic spline interpolation

Tags: interpolation, spline

Let S be a cubic spline interplant defined on the nodes $x_0=1, x_1=2, x_2=3$.

Make a sketch of a typical $S'''(x)$

Comment: Well, if it's cubic, perhaps you could guess something related to its third derivative?

Comment: If $y= ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d$ what **is** the  third derivative of y?

Comment: I mean I understand that it's a constant.  I'm just confused by the question.  Is it just a graph y= c?